# Angular 2 scroll to top after loading

Tags: angular, typescript, loading, scrolltop

I am adding a loading while getting a data. And in my view list there are pagination and page size. So my problem is that whenever I tried to change the page size and move to other pages right after loading it doesn't move scroll to the top. I already added `this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;` after my loading but it doesn't work.

These are my code in getting a data:

```
`getProducts() {
    this.productService
       .getProducts(this.args)
       .subscribe(
          data => {
              this.data = data;
              this.loadingService.hide();
              this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
          },
          (error) =>
                console.log(error);
          }       
      );
    }`
```

Comment: window.scrollTo(0, 0) works for me on ngOnInit().

Comment: I tried using it also but it doesn't work @harold_mean2

Comment: try `setTimeout( () => {window.scrollTo(0, 0);}, 0);`

Comment: Try this  this.scrollTopDiv.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.scrollTo(0,0);` in **ngOnit**. So it should look like this

`ngOnInit() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

**component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="goTop()">goTop</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class Component {
    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
    ) {}
    goTop() {
        this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my end. I don't know why.

**here is my code for my paginator.component.html**


`<button class="paginator-navigation-previous ui icon basic button" 
            [class.disabled]="pageIndex === 0"
            (click)="onPrevious()">
        <i class="chevron left icon"></i>
   </button>
    <button (click)="goTop()" class="paginator-navigation-next ui icon basic button"
            [class.disabled]="pageIndex === lastPage"
            (click)="onNext()">
        <i class="chevron right icon"></i>
    </button>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({...})
    export class MyPage{
      @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
```

add to inside subscribe

this.content.scrollToTop();

Referance; http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/